# Unable to Load Php.ini settings in MAC OS X v10.11.12

Tags: php, macos, mamp-pro

Its been a while I have started working with Php. Here is my exact problem. I am working on OSx el capitan. I installed MAMP PRO. I wanted to increase `upload_max_filesize` parameter. I am changing exactly the same file that is displayed in `phpinfo();` but still no hopes. Can someone please help me out with this. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to restart Apache after making your changes.  You can do it through the MAMP GUI or:

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/bin
./stop.sh
./start.sh
```

Are you using MAMP PRO?  If so, the configuration files may be being overwritten by a template on each server start.  Try editing the php.ini for your version of PHP in the following directory:

```
/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/
```

Comment: That made my day brother! Tysm.